# Compile Error: Object Required

Tags: vba, excel, object, compiler-errors

I'm having an issue with a

> Compile error: Object Required

I checked similar problems that have been solved on the site, but for some reason I am still having the issue.

The code I am using adds rows in between rows with non-matching cells under Column H (Column 8). It works most of the time, but one data set includes numbers and ends with cells that have letters and numbers in the cell in the cell. Let me know if you see something I am missing.

```
Sub SepP1()

Sheets("Format Area (Paste Here)").Activate

Dim LR As Long
Dim j As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Set LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row 'I AM GETTING THE ERROR HERE

i = 2

For j = 2 To LR

i = i + 1

If Cells(j, "H").Value = Cells(i, "H") Then

ElseIf Cells(j, 8).Value <> Cells(i, 8) Then
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Rows(i).Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown
    Rows(i).Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown
    Rows(i).Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown
    j = j + 3
    i = i + 3
    End If

Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: There's a bunch of questions concerned with the same error message. None of those answer your question? If yes, then at least extract a minimal example first, your question is off-topic without it.

Answer (score 1):

Only use `Set` when dealing with object variables. A `Long` is a number, not an object.

Change this:

```
Set LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row
```

To this:

```
LR = Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: braX you beat me to it.
I also noticed that every time you you insert rows you won't evaluate all your data, since your last row is not incremented.  If you want all the data in your coulmn, you'll have increment LR = LR +3 when you do the i=i+3 and j=j+3

Comment: Darn! Such a simple fix. Thanks so much for the help!